# "They never.....I don't either" or "They never...I do neither."

Tags: negation, determiners

Could you please tell me, which sentence is correct?

> "They never go skiing and I **don't either**"

or

> "They never go skiing and I **do neither."**

"I **don't either**" kind of sounds more natural to me, moreover, **"never"** is a negative word and we need to use the negative form of the verb **"to do"** (**don't**).

Is my assessment correct?

Comment: They never go skiing and nor do I.

Answer (score 3):

If you slightly change your second sentence they will mean the same

> They never go skiing and I don't either.
>
> They never go skiing and neither do I.

that none of you go skiing.

Using

> I do neither

usually means you are denying a choice of two

> Do you ski or climb?
>   I do neither, I prefer to walk.